# Keyboard message in 32 bit and 64 bit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a 32-bit windows application( with platform target: x86). It processes windows messages to identify keyboard key pressed.
I need to change its platform target to : Any CPU for 64 bit platform, but on changing its platform type to Any CPU, it is not working. When I debugged I found out that there was a difference in value of rawinput.keyboard.Message for both the configurations, for eg, when control key is pressed, it is 256 for x86 but 29 for Any CPU

Here, Message is a variable of type uint which is filled from Lparam value of window message.

how can i make it generic?

CODE:

```
private void ProcessInputCommand(Message message)
    {
        uint dwSize = 0;

        // First call to GetRawInputData sets the value of dwSize,
        // which can then be used to allocate the appropriate amount of memory,
        // storing the pointer in "buffer".
        UnsafeNativeMethods.GetRawInputData(message.LParam,
                         UnsafeNativeMethods.RID_INPUT, IntPtr.Zero,
                         ref dwSize,
                         (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)));

        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)dwSize);
        try
        {
            // Check that buffer points to something, and if so,
            // call GetRawInputData again to fill the allocated memory
            // with information about the input
            if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero &&
                UnsafeNativeMethods.GetRawInputData(message.LParam,
                                 UnsafeNativeMethods.RID_INPUT,
                                 buffer,
                                 ref dwSize,
                                 (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER))) == dwSize)
            {
                // Store the message information in "raw", then check
                // that the input comes from a keyboard device before
                // processing it to raise an appropriate KeyPressed event.

                RAWINPUT raw = (RAWINPUT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(RAWINPUT));

                if (raw.header.dwType == UnsafeNativeMethods.RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
                {
                    // Filter for Key Down events and then retrieve information 
                    // about the keystroke
                    if (raw.keyboard.Message == UnsafeNativeMethods.WM_KEYDOWN || raw.keyboard.Message == UnsafeNativeMethods.WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
                    {
                        ushort key = raw.keyboard.VKey;
                     }
```

(rest of the code to process keys)
.
.

GetRawInputData:

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    extern internal static uint GetRawInputData(IntPtr hRawInput, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize, uint cbSizeHeader);
```

Comment: Please post relevant code of extracting `uint` from `Lparam`

Comment: Hm. How is `GetRawInputData` defined? (Maybe the needed P/Invoke attributes are absent?)

Comment: Are you using the x86/x64 safe version of `RAWINPUT` structure? see http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/RAWINPUT.html

Answer (score 7):

The `RAWINPUT` struct uses an explicit layout, which requires different field offsets for 64-bit.

[Pinvoke.Net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/RAWINPUT.html) offers a x86/x64 safe implementation of `RAWINPUT` which you can use:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains the raw input from a device. 
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RawInput
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Header for the data.
    /// </summary>
    public RawInputHeader Header;
    public Union Data;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Union
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Mouse raw input data.
        /// </summary>
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RawMouse Mouse;
        /// <summary>
        /// Keyboard raw input data.
        /// </summary>
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RawKeyboard Keyboard;
        /// <summary>
        /// HID raw input data.
        /// </summary>
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RawHID HID;
    }
}
```